# Preserve uppercase in tagcloud

Tags: r, tag-cloud

I want to make a tag cloud to visualize the gene frequency.

```
library(wordcloud)

genes_snv <- read.csv("genes.txt", sep="", header=FALSE)

wordcloud(genes_snv$V1,
          min.freq=15,
          scale=c(5,0.5),
          max.words=100,
          random.order=FALSE,
          rot.per=0.3,
          colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

This is my code, but it converts everything to lowercase (not useful with gene names). How can I avoid this?

`genes.txt` starts with

```
Fcrl5
Etv3
Etv3
Lrrc71
Lrrc71
(...)
```

Comment: Make genes_snv$V1 into a vector (gene <- genes_snv$V1) and just try, i think it works

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately still the same (lowercase) wordcloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `freq` argument is missing `wordcloud` calls `tm::TermDocumentMatrix`, which I guess internally calls function `tolower` before computing frequency.

To avoid calls to `tm` we can supply our own frequency, see example:

```
# dummy data
set.seed(1)
genes <- c("Fcrl5","Etv3","Etv3","Lrrc71","Lrrc71")
genes <- unlist(sapply(genes, function(i)rep(i, sample(1:100,1))))

# get frequency
plotDat <- as.data.frame(table(genes))

# plot
wordcloud(word = plotDat$genes, freq = plotDat$Freq,
          min.freq=15,
          scale=c(5,0.5),
          max.words=100,
          random.order=FALSE,
          rot.per=0.3,
          colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

[image]